# Optimizar String eliminando texto entre contenedores /* y */

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código que crea elimina lo que hay entre medias de un String que comience con `/*` y termine con `*/`. El problema es que creo que si se tratara de un String muy grande, supondría un problema de optimización de la memoria del programa.

```
public class EntradaTeclado {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cadenaLimpia = ""
    boolean addChar = true;
    System.out.printf("Introduzca una frase que contenga los caracteres /* y */ \n");
    String palabra = ""
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
    palabra = scr.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++) {
        if ((i + 2) < palabra.length() && palabra.substring(i, i + 2).equals("/*")) {
            addChar = false;
        } else if (i > 3 && palabra.substring(i - 2, i).equals("*/")) {
            addChar = true;
        } else if (addChar == true) {
            cadenaLimpia = cadenaLimpia + palabra.substring(i, i + 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Cadena sin los caracteres /* y */: " + cadenaLimpia);
}
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias, un saludo.

Comment: podrias proporcionar un caso de entrada y salida, creo entender tu idea pero seria mucho mejor si dieras el ejemplo.

Comment: Uso de .replace(viejo caracter, nuevo caracter),
cadena.replace("/*","")
https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replace

Answer (score 2):

Lo adecuado es usar una `REGEX`, el cual elimine todo lo contenido entre `/*` y  `*/`:

```
    cadenaLimpia =  palabra.replaceAll("/\\*.*\\*/", "");
```

Lo implementarias de esta forma:

```
public class EntradaTeclado {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cadenaLimpia = ""
    boolean addChar = true;
    System.out.printf("Introduzca una frase que contenga los caracteres /* y */ \n");
    String palabra = ""
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
    palabra = scr.nextLine();

    cadenaLimpia =  palabra.replaceAll("/\\*.*\\*/", "");

    System.out.println("Cadena sin los caracteres /* y */: " + cadenaLimpia);
}
```

Ejemplo entrada:

```
Hola Stackoverflow /* adios */soy Martin
```

Salida:

```
Cadena sin los caracteres /* y */: Hola Stackoverflow soy Martin
```

Answer (score -1):

String de java tiene un método `replace` que reemplaza una cadena de caracteres por otra. Luego tu método quedaría muy simplificado:

```
public class EntradaTeclado {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cadenaLimpia = ""
        boolean addChar = true;
        System.out.printf("Introduzca una frase que contenga los caracteres /* y */ \n");
        String palabra = ""
        Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
        palabra = scr.nextLine().replace("/*","").replace("*/","");
}
System.out.println("Cadena sin los caracteres /* y */: " + palabra);
```

}

Comment: Hola, me parece que lo que desea es eliminar lo que se encuentra en medio de  /* y */ , saludos.

Comment: Esto no resuelve el problema del OP porque sólo incluye en la cadena resultante, lo que NO está entre los caracteres que indica.